# How do I replace a single word in a String variable with an element in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, string, arraylist

```
ArrayList<String> nounsList = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> verbsList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

(arrays lists are created from the contents of two files)

```
while((line_2 = wordReader2.readLine()) != null){
  //save all words in nouns.txt to array
  nounsList.add(line_2);
}

while((line_3 = wordReader3.readLine()) != null){
  //save all words in verbs.txt to array
  verbsList.add(line_3);
}

String libStory = "A paragraph is a series of related sentences developing a central idea, called the topic. Try to think about paragraphs in terms of thematic unity: a paragraph is a sentence or a group of sentences that supports one central, unified idea. Paragraphs add one idea at a time to your broader argument";

Random rand = new Random(); //required to pick random noun in nounsList array
int randElement;

    for (int y = 0; y < libStory.length(); y++) {
  
      randElement = rand.nextInt(nounsList.size());

      libStory.replace("paragraph", nounsList.get(randElement)); 
 

  }//end of for loop
```

It shows that an error (incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String).

WHAT I WANT TO DO: I want to select a specific word(paragraph) from my string variable (libStory) and replace it from another word that is an element in my arrayList (nounsList).
Any suggests how to achieve this? Or how to fix my code to achieve this? Thank you in advance.

EDIT: What if I have a string  ("A % is a series of related sentences developing a central %, called the %. Try to think about paragraphs in terms of thematic unity: a paragraph is a % or a group of % that supports one central, unified idea")           and I want to replace the placeholder (%) with a different element in a array each time each time another % occurs?

Comment: There are no `#` in your string. What are you thinking you're going to replace?

Comment: Sorry, I just fixed it, it should be paragraph. @SilvioMayolo

Comment: Why are you using a for loop if ou just want to replace one word?

Comment: I want to use a loop because paragraph is repeated multiple times in the string @Eritrean

Comment: (My work it actually longer I just need this idea to word)@Eritrean

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a for loop if your goal is to replace **each** accurance of `"paragraph"` with **one** random element from your list. The method    `String.replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)` will do it for you. From the java doc:

> Replaces each substring of this string that matches the literal target
> sequence with the specified literal replacement sequence.

```
    ArrayList<String> nounsList = ...

    String libStory = "A paragraph is a series of related ...";
    
    Random rand = new Random();
    
    libStory = libStory.replace("paragraph", nounsList.get(rand.nextInt(nounsList.size())));

    System.out.println(libStory);
```

Just don't forget to assign the replaced string to your original string, i.e

```
libStory = libStory.replace("paragraph",...
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on description and comments, to replace all occurrences of "paragraph" with a random noun, you can use `replace()`:

```
List<String> nounsList = Arrays.asList("paragraph", "series", "sentences");
String libStory = "A paragraph is a series of related sentences developing a central idea, called the topic. Try to think about paragraphs in terms of thematic unity: a paragraph is a sentence or a group of sentences that supports one central, unified idea. Paragraphs add one idea at a time to your broader argument";

Random rand = new Random(); //required to pick random noun in nounsList array

int randElementIndex = rand.nextInt(nounsList.size());
libStory = libStory.replace("paragraph", nounsList.get(randElementIndex));

System.out.println(libStory);
```

Output:

```
A series is a series of related sentences developing a central idea, called the topic. Try to think about seriess in terms of thematic unity: a series is a sentence or a group of sentences that supports one central, unified idea. Paragraphs add one idea at a time to your broader argument
```

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful? Another question -
What if I have a string  ("A % is a series of related sentences developing a central %, called the %. Try to think about paragraphs in terms of thematic unity: a paragraph is a % or a group of % that supports one central, unified idea")           and I want to replace the placeholder (%) with a different element in a array each time each time another % occurs? @Most Needed Rabbit